# How to fill white space with the image

Tags: html, css

I want the image to fill in the column of the page:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtgcW.jpg

I am trying to recreate a website to test my skills the website is:-https://www.simplesite.com

It is working when I assign it to the body but when I assign it to the div then there is white space below. I have tried a lot of things still can't get rid of this white space. Any help would be appreciated
HTML:-

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="header">
    <title>SimpleSite</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="contain">
      <Section id="Navbar">
        <nav id="mainNavbar" class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md  fixed-top  pt-3">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">SimpleSite</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navLinks" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navLinks">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link">Make a free website or blog</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link">Customer Service</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link">Features</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Themes</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Our Blog</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Careers</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item" id="button">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">LOG IN</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  <i class="fas fa-globe" style="font-size: 20px;"></i> English
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Español</a>
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Français</a>
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dansk</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </Section>

      <Section id="bgimage">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="special">
              <h1 class="text-center text-white">Create your website in <span>three simple steps</span></h1>
              <p class="text-center text-white"><strong>-it's free!-</strong></p>
              <button class="btn btn-danger rounded-pill"><span>START HERE</span></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Section>

      <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:-

```
#mainNavbar .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Tahoma, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #EA1C2C;
  font-weight: 900;
}

#mainNavbar .nav-link {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

#mainNavbar .nav-item {
  margin-left: 1.2rem;
}

#button .btn-success {
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 125px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#special {
  padding-top: 33%;
}

#special h1 {
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 1.7px;
}

#special p {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 2.0px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

#special span {
  font-weight: 600;
}

#special button {
  margin-top: 1.2rem;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 40%;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.contain {
  background: url("imgs/starter5.jpg") center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: ;
}
```

Comment: in `.contain` set `background-size` to `cover`

Comment: @ciekals11 tried that already still not working. it is only covering half of the page and half is white space below i shared a screenshot please check it

Comment: So you want this image to fill entire window?

Comment: @ciekals11 yes i need the image to fill in the enitre window and then i want to add some other content below like dey did  on www.simplesite.com

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hero_image.asp. This should help

Comment: then add to `.contain` property `height: 100vh;` and `background-size: cover;`

Comment: @ciekals11 thanks to you its working now xD.

Comment: i'm glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this jsfiddle link. Hope this solves your problem. Below is the same code.

```css
#mainNavbar .navbar-brand {
    font-size:2.4rem;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Tahoma, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #EA1C2C;
    font-weight: 900;
}
#mainNavbar .nav-link   {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
#mainNavbar .nav-item   {
    margin-left: 1.2rem;
}
 #button .btn-success {
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 125px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
#special    {
  padding-top: 33%;
}
#special h1 {
    font-size: 55px;
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 1.7px;
}
#special p  {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 2.0px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
#special span   {
    font-weight: 600;
}
#special button {
    margin-top: 1.2rem;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 40%;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.contain {
    background: url("https://previews.123rf.com/images/dolgachov/dolgachov1407/dolgachov140701912/29971506-business-interview-employment-and-office-concept-business-team-with-tablet-pc-computer-interviewing-.jpg") center center / cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: ;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Google Font -->
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="header">

    <title>SimpleSite</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="contain">
    <Section id="Navbar">
        <nav id="mainNavbar" class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md  fixed-top  pt-3">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">SimpleSite</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navLinks" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navLinks">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a href="" class="nav-link">Make a free website or blog</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a href="" class="nav-link">Customer Service</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a href="" class="nav-link">Features</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Themes</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Our Blog</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Careers</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
                  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item" id="button">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">LOG IN</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fas fa-globe" style="font-size: 20px;"></i> English   
                        </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Español</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Français</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dansk</a>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
      </nav>
      </Section>


    <Section id="bgimage">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" id="special">
                    <h1 class="text-center text-white">Create your website in <span>three simple steps</span></h1>
                    <p class="text-center text-white"><strong>-it's free!-</strong></p> 
                    <button class="btn btn-danger rounded-pill"><span>START HERE</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </Section>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/nartkmud/4/

Answer (score 0):

First of all You need the background size to fit the fold, which means set it to cover (please note that the image size should be 1920x1080 to look good and not pixelated).

add/change this:

```
.contain {
  background: url("imgs/starter5.jpg") 50% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

If the image is good than it should fill all the 1st fold of the page!

Answer (score 0):

Your css need little modification. Please try the below height property in your contain class :

```
.contain {
    background: url(imgs/starter5.jpg) center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;

}
```